# Cannot get Joule thief to work

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, joule-thief

For a few weeks now I've been trying to construct a Joule thief using a schematic commonly found on the web:

[image: https://cdn.instructables.com/FFY/9JKD/G33OYPJO/FFY9JKDG33OYPJO.LARGE.jpg.]

[image]

It consists of an NPN transistor, a 1 kΩ resistor, two coils wound around a ferrite core, and a 0.5 V battery. I've tried at least 10 different NPN transistors that I've salvaged from broken equipment and CFL light bulbs to no avail.

I have ensured that the windings are correctly connected where the opposite end is twisted together at the positive supply. None of these attempts resulted in a greater voltage across the collector-emitter leads.

I decided to buy a 2N3904 transistor since I have seen that Joule thief circuits have been made with them online.

Whats different from the circuits I have found online on websites and YouTube videos is that I did not connect any LED across the collector-emitter leads so I then assumed a diode was needed for some reason. However, the diode I connected made no difference, the results were the same.

Then I thought that the cell's voltage wasn't enough to overcome the barrier voltage between the base and emitter  so I used a cell with a voltage of 1.5 V, however, across the collector-emitter my multimeter read 0.99 V instead of an increased voltage.

I would like to know what I have done incorrectly and why none of these circuits has worked for me.

Comment: A picture of your circuit might help.

Comment: The purpose of the LED is to light up. The purpose of the rest of the circuit is to make the LED light up... The circuit doesn't need a diode there to function.

Comment: We can't see what you did, so can't advise what you may have done incorrectly. Photos please.

Comment: Assuming you got the circuit correct, the most likely error is in the transformer. A picture or description of that would help.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Q3Fqt

Comment: @Ian The usual way (you didn't describe it in enough detail to my liking, though I can see how you might argue that I should still be able to tell from what you did say) of winding the core is to start with a length of wire and fold it in half without cutting at the bend. There is a winding process that follows. Your picture is too fuzzy to tell. So how exactly did you wind this? And where did you get the core? Also, make sure to use an LED that requires significantly more voltage than the battery provides. A diode will NOT work here.

Comment: Assuming you have double-checked the pinout of this transistor and all connections on the breadboard, I would assume the transformer is the problem. I had success with a similar thoroid with 2 x 10 windings. Just to be sure, experiment with reversing one winding. Your photo does not have focus on the coil so it's hard to inspect it. What I do is: 1) draw the actual schematic, 2) draw the layout, 3) build. On problems: check all connections with a beeper.

Comment: Is it just me or do you not see an led here? Instead, there's a glass diode?

Comment: @Passerby -- No, it's not just you, you've found the problem: there's no LED!  That's a generic diode, looks like a 1N4148, and is not made to Light up at all!

Answer (score 3):

Your meter won't show anything. The output is actually voltage spikes of 4 to 40 kHz that in this setup may reach 25-70V. To see this, do as follows: In the above circuit, place a small 30-100uF/250V capacitor across the Collector-Emitter with diode in series with the capacitor. (Diode placed in upper capacitor arm direct toward capacitor.)

This capacitor will quickly collect the maximum voltage of your Joule Thief and show you a correct reading when you attach a meter to the capacitor. You will be surprised at the voltage.

Below I am presenting a fragment of your circuit, with the capacitor and diode setup to measure the voltage. Please ignore values of elements as they popped up by themselves - actually any capacitor and diode will do...

If you get nothing:

1. try switching ends of coils around.
2. try using variable resistor instead of 1k fixed resistor (0-1k) and try different settings. Use voltage source 1-2V

Best of luck.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZDQgC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I found the pot to work for me.  Instead of 1k resistor the circuit fired at .8 ohms.  Also if the source voltage is too high the circuit shuts down.  Might try a pot on your source voltage too.  Anyway got mine to work with .8 volts.  Base resistor .8 to .5 ohms.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see this didn't get resolved one way or another.

Let's assume a couple of things:

- Toroid inductance is 100uH
- LED forward drop is 3.5V
- Max power for LED is 20mA * 3.5V = 70mW
- 1.5V battery

Ok, let's simulate ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCCsB0AM8MYsBTAtAdhLaAmAnJACyRhiS4az65ixZEBsUIRAzFOmQFAAq4NVgA4QlXCHzNY2OAnzyFipfnAg0OOUPI1IkthlxtDM2I1oUmutiSqxxOBdwBO4XCLLiwbgfdG543ADmIIxEfmGhokTSMdwALlHSYIJiPtiqOJCM+F74QrhMjJDWQiI4VG5gjGzURfRFKnTSACYoAGYAhgCuADZx3ADuogYSzKlgGFKDw+KSIGxszHOw3NYgbQPNTgD2AA4AOgCObNCQqvjQRlwQ0jBCkKWMGGBE-kRka0ncVeKLInN-cCMaTiDZbPZHE5nGIZOBgaapXAFEJhJFhFZDVJEESpWKYkZJbx41xlFHpFYANzJLwiYQ85NYSVODMy00i0ki9Ix1KItPC2ARI38OKFyJWwUBVWkksm5OmCyWzEBy2mXn+zDV4C8AqGmuS4gKSUE3M1cylox1QOk2JJwktmsJIhtJuBdv1FpNght5pVACNwLz5gb6FrYgAPcDFUQcZJYXDMOnMADKAw6uwAhNwI2cwGt9OB84nwKcAGpZ+b4JJGKDeXNnIsAIR6XRQ+wAzgAZACiABF2yW2u2ju2oWXtiwbqw6FhoXh0uIzmxuOONSAsHWJmdZ3Yc7CzJBl1rVOu2KQMFuZBBPDI2F4D0A)):

[image]

I increased the base resistor to 2.2k to bring the LED power within spec (~70mW.) You can adjust this - larger resistor, lower current, longer battery life.

Seems to work ok. Efficiency isn't too bad - about 87%.

Oscillates at about 66kHz, way too fast to see with a voltmeter. This frequency depends mainly on the inductance. More turns will increase inductance and decrease the frequency. If your meter shows anything on the LED, it will be about 2V RMS.

More about making these coil thingos here: https://www.66pacific.com/calculators/toroid-coil-winding-calculator.aspx

From this website, to make 100uH with a ferrite (type 43) core you need 23 turns.

Now as to why your circuit fails, check the polarity of the wires. Near as I can tell from your photo you've failed to flip one of the windings. That, and you're not using an LED, but we'll set that aside for now.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information, I will bet your lunch its the DIRECTIONS of your windings in your transformer.  Again, assuming you're attempting a bifilar configuration, I recommend this:

Bare bobbin in one hand, two of your cat-6 strands of different color ran CLOCKWISE as a pair left to right as your bobbin is held sideways. Run one layer, strip only one color strand, both sides.  Cover with a piece of paper first and then CLOCKWISE left to right over the first layer and paper, coil only one wire, end to end, 4 layers if possible.  Recommend paper between each winding, as it keeps your turns tight and clean with no digging or jumping.  Either cut to size or rip excess off.

Your leads from strand one of layer one are primary, the leads of strand 3 from your second winding of the same coil.  We are not using strand 2; its for spacing turns only.

I failed to mention this is wound on an ecore and bobbin.

Still not working?

Reverse your connections to your transformer on the primary side.  Disconnect your power source first.
Reconnect.

Still bupkis? Remove clipped connector to your transistors collector and while connected to power source, tap all 3 contacts of the transistor.  If you see the bulb light and stay lit but not brightly, make sure to tap the base and emitter, too.  One often lights and one other may be real bright!