# Why don't simulators work with a self-oscillating voltage booster circuit using a transformer and a transistor?

Tags: transformer, oscillator, simulation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4O1e8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I built this circuit (real not simulated.) With a 3V DC source, the output voltage is about 37V using a 1:14 transformer.  I think this is a "self-oscillating" circuit.

When I try to simulate the circuit in Falstad or EveryCircuit, the circuit does not appear to oscillate and so the transformer and booster circuit don't work.

I don't understand how to use CircuitLab, so I didn't test whether that would successfully simulate the oscillation.

I built the circuit in CircuitLab in order to insert it here.

Can anyone tell me why simulators have trouble with this circuit?  Will CircuitLab successfully simulate this? If so I'll learn how to use it.  I'm a beginner so I might not have described this correctly.

Here's a photo of the Snap Circuits part I'm using as the transformer: [image]

Comment: can you provide a link to the falstaad simulation?

Comment: Have you tried adding a little AC noise to the source. It could be failing the way bistables sometimes fail in simulation, because the initial conditions in the simulator coincide with a metastable state which is exceedingly unlikely in the real world.

Comment: The inductance of the transformer affects the oscillation - try to match that in your sim.

Comment: This answer might be useful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350823/cannot-get-joule-thief-to-work/618758#618758

Comment: @FrancoVS Here's a link to the falstad simulation: https://tinyurl.com/y3gr2uxg

Comment: The parasitic details , Lpri, coupling factor , Self-resonant frequency, and stray capacitance are not shown on the schematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the simulator that's isn't working. The challenge is to accurately model your circuit: not just its connections, but also the circuit elements. Even then, simulations can bomb out when they encounter cases their internal modeling can’t handle, as we’ll see below.

The thing you're making has a complex circuit element in it: a transformer. It will have its own characteristics besides its turns ratio. These include, among others: inductance, coil resistance, and parasitic capacitance.

If you know your transformer's characteristics you can add these to your simulation.

With your 'audio' transformer parameters (3.5mH primary, 1:14, [reference example here](https://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/114225.pdf)), here's what we get ([simulate it here](https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BOJyWoVaAOSBmMYEAWJANkhIHYAmAVnUIpBqciYFMBafAKDBPQ4UcJEByqZMokhNHjJrGHBzMwhaOJoVVGrYQ0Z4yyFRJgK2SIWk5jOUYsj4%20cTYUJ0c2c-dhVb7mlcqN1MEOxgkbgB3UUwEETFg2PjRVUIobgAXWMJJLnFkhLAC1gguaEIwOFoaZ0sEYsYOGDIqcQJaP2oER3A4EAATNgAzAEMAVwAbTOjC0RwqKRkOBYyYjjii4rmVxchZjmk82gSSJLEaEX2AJ1EaN1ll%20-SVmj2%20%20G4ADylIAQpmBxNKxBIt0tsADIAUQAIgAdADOgELyQBwf7wzncHvk8s95otFkMxlNMhxJmwBuAoFTFGADrixE8sSc1piXsygVjivI6VjlIsOS9CP19ut6UKQZtROKWRsUhxpbKEnyMhSBVKSC8zoKNSACSMJtNuABjVnql5i4XgaAkTh5CQVTD3MA4HDUZT8cKwRwHI6mw7LMjc9aS%20X9RWmkU7enmc0PSOCTCxl4x37cn4cBAmVK0UQNEHFMHgRYARVp6YoZFkcq0AioYRA4MWABUwIiwAAuVTfO4u%20Y2O5mPGMRsgABKZbuDSlmDsQIB09YI5htNuG1WDLyFeOMlKPsZSYjPIPavlOpuSzyzgvsiSrCoOCPftyINx%20wA5jt1yG%20NTuKvfRu16vO8957nkyr%20nkVjpPGIYQSGcgykQbLLAhO4HGhdo6okMEYeubTJtIN64cG2GIeGOEZKOuZMssCAVo88hUkKIDhNS0A0GBeJSJc3HxkIRQFJB2bcqqAG5EB%20D4oM%20rEj6vG7H6qzxgBV7CdiMqqUJqnbCpywSepykYQZXKiAJImafp2FamaMqYGRqH4ehpFsucM78gRGQAEaxDQIKuua3hcMQGTpo6s6uv8BDzAx4IiE21yjAAdgiwwAPbXAAtmw1yIgAsmlQyTMaZlEYBghlZ5pScPgsjQB0JxCpm8B0FcXq0iahznJ56lVSAFA1RAVDQD0VT0X5QhhJgboGN6nU2eVAGIawA1cGUOBYG0kDdLgbSYGAvEOLS6wLeyp23j63UBt1h2XWyCn0sy8bPk%20BmvtwAAOZmJqmQGBpSCgHFuxFmcIIP8ZVyzmYB%20xffKb1Ym4UE6hAgMfvDyOCgZSO-mllLvIQwh2FUGAwbqlJ2KWiIAJJGtweM4OgBNE7qHEGDmQ2seglOtgi1NefTICSMzgRCwosDMNJkgPp4VIAGKo7N8Co16iBoOrSCpCAAAK1wAJaZaM1wAJ400lAzjEamTJUabDcEAA)):

[image]

There's these differences between your diagram and this sim:

- Inductance added in
- Coil resistances added (see the datasheet reference) but you could also measure these with a voltmeter to confirm
- Primary is flipped to make the feedback work
- Reverse diode on the transistor base

Why the diode? The sim fails because the transformer flyback when Q1 shuts off makes a huge negative voltage spike, which causes the sim to fail to converge.

In the real world, probably the transistor is getting fried with excessive reverse Vbe (over 600V in the sim, until it stops.) You can remove the diode in the sim and see for yourself.

The LED isn't very happy either. It's also seeing large reverse voltage (-38V with the diode, much more without.) It won't live long either.

Maybe Snap wants to sell you some components when they die?

Comment: Are the two secondaries each 140 turns ?

Comment: 70 + 70, split in the middle.

Comment: Why do the transformer primary terminals need to be flipped in the simulator when they are not flipped in the actual circuit?

Comment: I would bet that they are flipped in the actual circuit too. Post a photo maybe? But that’s just one of several  reasons why your sim isn’t working.

Comment: The terminals need to be flipped like that so that the feedback polarity is right.

Comment: I don't know how to insert an image in these comments.  I'm making a Snap Circuits circuit using the Snap Circuits transformer part.  Here's a link to it on the manufacturer's website: [link](https://shop.elenco.com/consumers/transformer.html)  The only information I've been able to obtain about the transformer used in this part is from the manufacturer's technical support.  They told me it is a "typical audio transformer" and that the primary coil inductance is 3.5mH and the secondary coil inductance is 750mH. How can I tell the polarity?

Comment: Here's a link to the Falstad circuit that shows exactly how I have the Snap Circuits parts connected: [link](https://tinyurl.com/yy222n5r)

Comment: The inductance is useful info - I’ll revisit the sim with those values. As for polarity there should be a ‘dot’ on the coil showing that. You can insert an image by taking a picture, saving it, then using the ‘insert image/upload’ button on the post edit tool bar.

Comment: In the same Falstad circuit, if I flip the primary connections, the simulation works: [link](https://tinyurl.com/y66ctcfe)

Comment: I've added a photo of the Snap Circuits transformer to my original post.

Comment: Neither the Snap Circuits transformer part or the Falstad tapped-transformer component have polarity markings.  How can I tell their polarity?

Comment: The Falstad split transformer is positive polarity. That is, apply an AC voltage on its primary terminals and the same polarity comes out the secondary. The Falstad non-tapped transformer has a flip polarity option which will show the dots, the tapped one doesn’t have that option.

Comment: @AnnetteGates I tried your sims - the LED connection isn't right. At any rate, with the 'right' connections and transformer parameters the sim still fails: excessive flyback voltage on the transistor base causes the sim to fail convergence (basically, Falstad assumes the transistor is killed.) I'll post that presently.

Comment: When you say the Falstad split transformer is positive polarity, is that the same thing as saying that the primary and secondary are "in phase" and this would be indicated by both having dots at the top?  Maybe the Snap Circuits transformer is "out of phase" and if it were indicated, the primary dot would be at the top and the other at the bottom?  That would be why I don't need to flip the connections on the Snap Circuits part?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly the case: the Falstad transformer by default is ‘in phase’ even though it has no dots. For the Snap part you’d need to confirm transformer polarity by applying an ac signal and observing it with an oscilloscope.

Comment: In the Mouser datasheet you provide a link to, which of the six transformers on the datasheet do you think is the closest to the Snap Circuits transformer?

Comment: The second one, 1k / 8ohm, 12.6:1. Not exact, but similar.

Answer (score 7):

The transformer winding in the collector is the wrong way round. You need to swap the two connections such that when the collector goes towards ground, the base goes positive.

The dots on the windings indicate the polarity. If a terminal with a dot is connected to the collector, the base needs to connect to a terminal opposite to the dotted terminal.

Simulating oscillators can be tricky as there is no noise to start the oscillation. You may need to inject a pulse or experiment with the start-up conditions to achieve oscillation even if the circuit is correct.

Also with a 1:14 transformer the breakdown voltages on the LED and the transistor base-emitter junction will be exceeded.

Comment: By reversing the transformer connection as discussed, and changing the voltage source to a step input, it oscillates nicely: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/ckpz9arm4q69/converter/  Feel free to paste this into your answer if you like.  Just run the time-domain simulation with "skip initial'.

Comment: To clarify:  It oscillates and generates the expected voltage at its output.  How accurately it models the physical circuit is another matter.

Comment: Once I got the transformer polarity right (out-of-phase) by flipping the connections to the primary coil, the simulation worked.

Answer (score 4):

These sorts of simple self oscillating schemes rely on transformer saturation to define the on time by volt seconds applied to the winding. This is a close relative to the blocking oscillator. You must work on your transformer model to include saturation.